# AWS wont let me delete custom Security Groups that I had created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and,

Here's the drill:
- Logged in to AWS with root admin credentials.
- I created few security groups in AWS.
- Terminated all the EC2 instances that I had.
- Deleted ELB successfully.
- Deleted RDS successfully.
- Using default VPC and no Elastic IPs.

Now, when I am trying to delete security groups, one group says its being referenced by another. When I try to delete the referenced one, it says that the security group is being referenced by a Network Interface.

We get two options here- **Associate with another group or Delete that Network Interface**. 
Trying first makes no sense as I want to get rid of all the Security Groups except the default (Like it was in the beginning). Still I tried that option and got the error "**You do not have permission to access the specified resource**" and it did not let me associate that Network Interface (Status-In Use) with any Security Group.
Tried deleting/detaching(force) that Network Interface and got an error message "**You do not have permission to access the specified resource**."

A similar issue can be found below without any known solution:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=99189&start=0&tstart=0

Unresolved Stackoverflow link: [issue in deleting VPC and network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232965/issue-in-deleting-vpc-and-network-interface)

I would really appreciate if someone hits me with a hammer of facts :)

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: That AWS forums question has correct and accepted answer: contact AWS support and they will fix it.

Comment: @DusanBajic Yes, support is a solution, but knowing from where the issue comes is better. That AWS forum doesn't show any accepted answer, just a ton of people complaining they have the same issue, and nobody answering them.

Comment: @arvymetal true!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, after having removed *load balancers*, *auto-scaling groups*, the *memcached cluster* and so on, I couldn't delete the *VPC*.

I had the feeling that there was some vicious circle between two *network interfaces* that I couldn't detach or modify and the *security group* itself that I couldn't remove as long as it was attached to the interfaces.

I ran the `aws elasticache describe-instances` command (I saw a reference to *elasticache* in a network interface description) to see if it would show something I missed.
And indeed, there was some **redis cluster** remaining, that I didn't see in the mess of the UI, which was some remnant of a long forgotten test. After having removed this cluster, I could delete the *VPC*.

So I'd say that kind of issue: **unauthorized access, even for admins** is mainly related to a **component managed by AWS**, and to the fact that the UI is far from friendly when it comes to know from where an error comes.

Comment: What I had observed is, if you delete it after some time, e.g after a day or two, it gets deleted. I didn't get much time to dive into the details but that's certainly very strange.

Comment: I also thought about waiting a few days, thinking that maybe some background process needs to do some cleaning on AWS side. But this issue happened to me 2 hours ago and I felt that if I postponed, things would remain like that for long...

Comment: Did we try AWS CLI? 
aws ec2 delete-security-group --group-name MySecurityGroup OR aws ec2 delete-security-group --group-id sg-903004f8
Ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/delete-security-group.html

Comment: Now that it's solved for me, I couldn't say if it would have worked. Usually, given that the UI is built over the AWS API, I get the same errors when using the CLI. But maybe they would have been more explicit or less misleading.

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=168376

It looks like sg-72bd411a does in fact reference itself. You'll need to go into it and remove the reference before you can delete it.